# Open elementary apps from the command-line

Tags: files, command-line, code

How can I open elementary apps from the [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)? Particularly Code and Files. I already found `/usr/bin/io.elementary.files` and `/usr/bin/io.elementary.code`, build they are not really convenient. Also, the latter doesn't detach from the terminal, so whenever the terminal window is closed, Code does the same.

Of course I can create an alias in the `.bashrc` file (which I did), but maybe there is a better way?

**UPDATE**:

Seems like the best route for files is adding the following line to the `.bashrc`:

`alias files='/usr/bin/io.elementary.files'`

So opening a dir from the terminal would be:

`files /path/to/dir`

For code, there still is the issue of detaching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides writing `io.elementary.code` or creating an alias there isn't any way to open a app from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I find that I don't want to open apps specifically from the command line, I just want to open a document and have whatever app is needed open it.

xdg-open to the rescue!

So `xdg-open ~/mypdf.pdf &` will automatically open my pdf document in Document Viewer. I need the `&` to put the terminal command into the background.

Beware - you might end up with lots of GTK css warnings with some apps, most of which can be ignored.

Comment: In some cases it's useful to open a file or dir in **Code** from the command line. Just like Sublime Text allows to.

Answer (score 0):

try "***pantheon-files***" on terminal to open the file manager.

Comment: It should be `io.elementary.files`. So `io.elementary.files /path/to/dir`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you want to change a command, but if you want, using an alias is the way

Now, about detaching a process from a terminal, if you add & to the end it will detach and then you can close the terminal if you want/need and the process will continue running.

Comment: There's also a little app called 'Alias' in the store, that's basically an alias GUI, if you don't want to use the terminal.